# Deleting Sharepoint Online Sharing Links Programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

Is it possible to delete Sharepoint online Sharing Links programmatically?.
Sharing Links are created by selecting a document and folder and click Share button.
I have noticed that it creates a sharepoint group in the backend, but removing this sharepoint group from RoleAssignments does not remove the link permanently.

Thanks for your help.

Sharing

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Sharing links are created as a unique permissions for the item. Deleting unique permissions will delete the link. Below is the example of how you can do it in PowerShell

```
$SiteUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/team"
$ListName = "Documents"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
$Ctx = Get-PnPContext

$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName
$ItemCount = $ListItems.Count
   
ForEach($Item in $ListItems)
{
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Links
    $ItemPermission =Get-PnPListItemPermission -List $ListName -Identity $Item.Id
    $RoleAssignments = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $Item -Property RoleAssignments

    ForEach($permission in $ItemPermission.Permissions)
    {
        If($permission.PrincipalName.StartsWith("SharingLinks"))
        {
            $Links.Add($permission.PrincipalId)
        }
    }
    
    ForEach($RoleAssignment in $RoleAssignments)
        {
           If($Links.Contains($RoleAssignment.PrincipalId))
           {
                $Item.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipalId($RoleAssignment.PrincipalId).DeleteObject()
                Invoke-PnPQuery
           }
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

ResetRoleInheritance resets all of the permissions of item including Direct Access, I dont want to touch any other permissions, just want to remove SharingLinks.

Comment: I've updated the script. Please try it. this will just delete the permissions given through shared link.

Comment: Thank you, the issue with deleting the role assignment is, it does not delete the sharing link properly, sharing link stays with the item in unhealthy state. And if someone shares the same item again, it brings back the old permissions.

Answer (score 0):

PnP core sdk provides an easy way to delete sharinglinks programmatically.

- PnP.Core.Model.SharePoint.IFolder.DeleteShareLinks();
  PnP.Core.Model.SharePoint.IFile.DeleteShareLinks();

It uses Microsoft Graph at the backend, but I find it quite difficult to do the same through Microsoft Graph as it needs guids of site, library and item as well. So before executing the graph end point, we need to get these guids through separate graph calls. PnP Core sdk does that in the background.